# python: how to make the result of split directly key, value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, split

If this is the desired result:

```
t = {'p': '011', 'or': 'artificial', 'pc': '3718'}
```

and this the list the dict should be made from:

```
s = ['p=011', 'or=artificial', 'pc=3718']
```

How can you write the key -value assignment and the split-function in one line? I mean something like this (which of course is not working):

```
t = dict()
for e in s:
    t[k] = v = k,v = e.split("=")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> s = ['p=011', 'or=artificial', 'pc=3718']
>>> dict(x.split('=') for x in s)
{'p': '011', 'or': 'artificial', 'pc': '3718'}
>>>
```